# How do I scale worldHires to plot coastlines correctly on R?

Tags: r, maps

I'm trying to overlay the coastlines and country borders onto the R map I've drawn.

I'm trying the simple **worldHires** function to do this but it's not scaling correctly to my map. I downloaded my data from https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded/data.UDel_AirT_Precip.html and the file name is precip.mon.total.v401

This is my code when I try to plot my map (excluding the first few lines of reading data and variables into R):

```
>image.plot(lon,lat,precip[,ncol(precip):1,8],
       main="Precipitation (August, 2001)", 
       xlab=expression(paste("Longitude(",degree,"E)")),
       ylab=expression(paste("Latitude(",degree,"N)")),
       zlim=c(0,15),xlim = c(min(lon),max(lon)), 
       ylim = c(min(lat),max(lat)),cex=0.5)
> map('world2Hires', fill=FALSE, add=T)
```

The boundary layer from world2Hires is very small, scaling from -90 to 90 for Latitude and 0 to 360 for Longitude.

My data's range is Latitude -180 to 180 and Longitude 0 to 720. So how do I scale the world2Hires to match my data? Or is that not possible? [See image in link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJgTv.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you seem to be mixing the latitude values (-90:90) degrees with the matrix indices. Since the map is of resolution 0.5 degrees, these run 0:360. The same for the longitudes.

So from your question, I am not sure whether the problem is that your vectors "lon" and "lat" are incorrect (they should probably be something like `lon=seq(0,360,by=0.5); lat=seq(-90,90,by=0.5)`). Obviously, the map() command expects the co-ordinates to be in degrees.

But the illustration on the link you provided, shows that the data is on longitude [0,360] while the data in worldHires is on [-180,180].
I think the simplest solution is to use "world2Hires", which is the same map but with longitudes shifted to [0,360], which should fit your map.

As a side remark, using worldHires is possibibly not the best choice of world map. The country borders in some parts of the world are outdated, and the high resolution is not so important at a global scale. Just using "world2" (the "2" again is for the shift to [0,360]) would probably look just as good on a global map.

I may add that in the very near future, the next version of "map" will make such shifting of longitudes much easier, whithout the need for an extra data set.